# png file is not getting displayed on HTML5 page

Tags: html

I have created a small web page. I placed the png file in the same location as my index.html. But it is not getting displayed.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <head>
    <title>Welcome to Learners lingo!! </title>
    <meta charset=“UTF-8”/>
    <link rel=“stylesheet” href=‘styles.css’ type=“text/css” >
    <meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0”>


  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#e6ecff">
    <header class=“mainHeader”> 
        <img src=‘logo.png’ alt=“logo” width="42" height="42">


        <nav><ul> 
            <li><a href=“#”>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href=“#”>About</a></li>
            <li><a href=“#”>Course material</a></li>
            <li><a href=“#”>Nasty Things</a></li>
            <li><a href=“#”>Contact</a></li>
        </ul></nav>
    </header>

    <div class=“mainContent”>
        <div class=“content”>
            <article class=“top content”>
                <header> 
                    <h2><a href=“#” title=“First Post”>First Post</a></h2>
                </header> 
                <footer>
                    <p> class=“post-info”>This post is written by Me !</p> 
                </footer> 
                <content> 
                    <p> Just this is one of the main content </p>
                </content>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>

    <aside class=“top-side-bar”>
        <article> 
            <h2> Top side bar</h2>
            <p> This is just a side bar </p>
        </article> 
    </aside> 

    <aside class=“middle-side-bar”>
        <article> 
            <h2> Middle side bar</h2>
            <p> This is just a side bar </p>
        </article> 
    </aside> 

    <aside class=“Bottom-side-bar”>
        <article> 
            <h2> Bottom side bar</h2>
            <p> This is just a side bar </p>
        </article> 
    </aside> 

    <footer class=“Main Footer”>
        <p> Copyright &copy; <a href=“http://www.learnerslingoo.net”> Learners Lingoo </a> </p>
    </footer> 
  </body>

</html>
```

Could someone help me understand why the image is not getting displayed. I have been trying to resolve it from couple of hours, but not sure what mistake am I doing. The file name is correct. A simple logo.png

[image]

Comment: You can open that image with an editor?

Comment: Yes, I am able to open the image with an editor. I just dragged it onto my tab and it displayed properly

Comment: Right click image and copy image location. Open this location with browser.

Comment: oh, yeah. The quotation marks created the problem. The link displayed as file:///Users/zombiepark/Desktop/%E2%80%98Images/logo.png%E2%80%99. When I removed the quotation mark in the code, automatically my image is displayed on the page. So just img src=logo.png alt=“logo” width="42" height="42"> is enough. No need of single or double quotation marks around logo.png . Interesting. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use regular single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes, not `“` or `‘`:

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="42" height="42">
<!--Here-^--------^-----^----^ -->
```

Comment: Additionally, he used these wrong type of quotes too many times in the whole HTML document.

Answer (score 2):

Change your quote signs from

```
src=‘logo.png’
```

to

```
src="logo.png"
```